# Dropping The First X Parts Of A Logger Name

Tags: java, log4j2

I've got a piece of Log4J2 config that looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And that'll print me out logging statements in the form of:

```
10:49:55.700 INFO  uk.co.ltheobald.myapp.packageA.Foo - Hello!
10:49:55.800 INFO  uk.co.ltheobald.myapp.packageA.Bar - Hello!
10:49:55.900 INFO  uk.co.ltheobald.myapp.packageA.subpackage.Foo - Hello!
```

I'd like to trim that down and remove the `uk.co.ltheobald.myapp.` part from each line.  I know I can set the package level to print the right most X packages using `%logger{2}`, so I'd get something like:

```
10:49:55.700 INFO  packageA.Foo - Hello!
10:49:55.800 INFO  packageA.Bar - Hello!
10:49:55.900 INFO  subpackage.Foo - Hello!
```

But that drops part of my package naming as I nest classes further down a package structure.

Surely there must be a way to say ignore the first four packages?  Something like `%logger{-4}` would be nice! Any clues anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a test and this Pattern removes the 4 first package names:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %replace{%logger}{^.*?\..*?\..*?\..*?\.}{} - %msg%n" />
```

You can even use (to minimize pattern):

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %replace{%logger}{^(.*?\.){4}}{} - %msg%n" />
```

Comment: I don't understand why other answers are upvoted but not this one, since it is the only suitable solution at this time, and that this answer was accepted as best answer by the OP...

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating your logger in the class?

If I try

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyMain.class.getName());
```

> Output 15:58:13.861 INFO  com.pkg1.MyMain  - something

I get the package name in the log output. However the following code just prints the class name.

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("pkg1.MyMain");
```

> Output: 15:57:33.814 INFO  pkg1.MyMain  - something

Comment: This actually changes the Logger used, which means, what ever configuration exists based on the Logger needs changing. If you use two or more libs with this approach you might get nameclashes in the Logs. i.e. in all logs, not just those where you choose to skip the first package parts.

Comment: I'm using "Logger.getLogger()" to get the logger. I'd rather not use Strings. As @JensSchauder mentions - you're likely to get clashes. Automatic refactoring of packages etc. would also not rename these strings for me.

Comment: I completely agree with the concerns. My code was a simple hack. For more elegant solution, you will need to implement your own layout.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the documentation.

I think RegexReplacement should be usable for this. It is probably not the fastest, but should be fairly easy to use.

The other alternative would be to write a custome Formatter

Answer (score 1):

Other people suggested creative workarounds, but might I suggest that you raise a feature request for this in the Log4j2 [Jira issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2)?

Comment: I certainly will do. If I get a chance to investigate the code, I'll code a patch for the feature

Comment: For anyone who's interested, here is the request I logged in JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-621